# Converting a string with list of dicts to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a string from a file which looks like:

`"[{key1:val1,key2:val2},{key1:val1,key2:val2}.....}]"`

How do I convert this string into a pandas dataframe with key1 and key2 as two columns?

I can think of string manipulations like first removing '[' and ']' characters and then splitting on '},{' , append '}' to each item which would give me a list of `"{key1:value1,key2:value2}"` strings and then performing operations on each item of the list.

But that will be a bit cumbersome. I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [73]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{'key1':'val1','key2':'val2'},{'key1':'val1','key2':'val2'}])
Out[73]:
   key1  key2
0  val1  val2
1  val1  val2
```

or from the JSON string:

```
import json

In [81]: s
Out[81]: '[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"},{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}]'

In [82]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(s))
Out[82]:
   key1  key2
0  val1  val2
1  val1  val2
```

Comment: `from_dict` expects the paramter to be a dict or a list of dicts. In my case I just have a string variable whose value is `[{key1:val1,key2:val2},{key1:val1,key2:val2}]`

Comment: @nishant, please see the second part of my answer

Comment: yup got it. I missed the 2nd part before.